# drawPath getting disjoint segment at reciving end canvas android

Tags: android, canvas, path, drawing

I am trying to make real time application based on canvas writing here multiple device will be connected with this application if i write something on canvas it should reflect on other devices which are connected with this app here my issue is i am able to write on canvas and its also writes smooth but when it comes to receiving end its getting disjoint segment not clear path visible on canvas.

I am using thread using `moveTo()` and `quadTo()`to and receiving points from server

**here images for reference** 
[Source writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWohj.png)
[Receiving end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JOdM.png)

Here is my code which i am trying

**onDraw method**

```
 @Override
            protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
                normal_canvas_draw=true;
                bckimage = getBackground();
                String col = "#333333".substring(1);
                col = col.toLowerCase();
                col = "#ff" + col;

                mc.setcanvas(canvas);

                paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint1.setDither(true);
                paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint1.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                paint1.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(30) );   // set the path effect when they join.


                paint.setDither(true);                    // set the dither to true
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       // set to STOKE
                paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
                paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      // set the paint cap to round too
                paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(30) );   // set the path effect when they join.
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);


                    mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                    mCanvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);


    /*
                for(Path p :paths)
                {
                    mCanvas.drawPath(p, paint1);
                }*/

                //mCanvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);

                //s = paths.size();
                s = type.size();
                Log.d("BLOCK", s + " , " + leftval.size());
                int j = 0, k = 0;

                canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);
                canvas.drawText(mc.getDisplaymsg(), mCanvas.getWidth()-200, 25, painttext);

                r = new Rect(10, 600, 100, 650);
            }
```

**onTouchEvent**

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if (mIsScrolling)
                sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            else
                sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            boolean touchcaptured = false;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                     path.reset();


//                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    boolean l = r.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());


                    if (markerMode)
                    {
                        isEraserDown="false";
                        isPenDown="false";
                        isMarkerDown="true";
                        path.moveTo(eventX,eventY);
                        startX=eventX/scalefactor;
                        startY=eventY/scalefactor;
                        mX=eventX;
                        mY=eventY;
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:eraserfunction(" + eventX / scalefactor + "," + eventY / scalefactor + "," + mc.getdrawAttributes1() + ")");
                    }

                    else if (eraseMode)
                    {
                        isEraserDown="true";
                        isPenDown="false";
                        isMarkerDown="false";
                        System.out.println("--Eraserfromtouch");
                        path.moveTo(eventX,eventY);
                        startX=eventX/scalefactor;
                        startY=eventY/scalefactor;
                        mX=eventX;
                        mY=eventY;
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:eraserfunction(" + eventX / scalefactor + "," + eventY / scalefactor + "," + mc.getdrawAttributes1() + ")");
                    }

                    else if (blockerase) {
//                        left=(int) event.getX();
//                        right=left+1;
//                        top=(int) event.getY();
//                        bottom=top+1;
                        rx = (int) event.getX();
                        ry = (int) event.getY();
                    }

                    /*------------------- Pendown when we touch on mobile screen------*/
                    else if (penmode) {
                        isPenDown="true";
                        isEraserDown="false";
                        isMarkerDown="false";
                        System.out.println("---pen-down---"+eventX+","+eventY);
                        int historySize = event.getHistorySize();

                if(isPenDown=="true")
                {
                    path.moveTo(eventX,eventY);
                    mX = eventX;
                    mY = eventY;
                    startX=eventX/scalefactor;
                    startY=eventY/scalefactor;
                    mc.setXY(eventX / scalefactor, eventY / scalefactor);
                    MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:penDown(0,0,'pen')");
                }
                else
                {

                }

                       // System.out.println(" Lcal x"+eventX+" y"+eventY+" x2"+eventX+" y2"+eventY);
                    } else if (rectanglemode) {
                        rx = (int) event.getX();
                        ry = (int) event.getY();
                    } else if (linemode) {
                        rx = (int) event.getX();
                        ry = (int) event.getY();
                    } else if (circlemode) {
                        cx = (int) event.getX();
                        cy = (int) event.getY();
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:circleDown(" + cx / scalefactor + "," + cy / scalefactor + ")");
                    } else if (textmode) {
                        cx = (int) event.getX();
                        cy = (int) event.getY();
                        //MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:drawtext(" +cx + "," + cy+","+"Hello World"+")");
                    }
                    //invalidate();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (markerMode) {
                        if (isMarkerDown.equals("true")) {
                            System.out.println("Marker Move");
                            Log.d("MARKER", "Hi im marker");
                            String col = mc.getdrawAttributes().substring(1);
                            col = col.toLowerCase();
                            col = "#ff" + col;
                            int coll = Color.parseColor(col);
                            paint.setColor(coll);
                            paint.setAlpha(10);
                            paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
                            if (bckimage == null) {

                            } else {
                                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR));
                            }
                            MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:marker1(" + eventX / scalefactor + "," + eventY / scalefactor + ")");
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                        path.quadTo(mX,mY,(mX+event.getX())/2,(mY+event.getY())/2);

                        mX=event.getX();
                        mY=event.getY();
                    }
                    else if (eraseMode)
                    {
                        if(isEraserDown=="true")
                        {
                            System.out.println("--Eraserfromtouch--MOVE");

                            System.out.println("Marker Move");
                            Log.d("Eraser", "Im eraser");

                            String thh = mc.getdrawAttributes1();
                            float f = Float.parseFloat(thh);
                            paint.setStrokeWidth(f);

                            if (bckimage == null) {
                                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ERASE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                // setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
                                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
                                MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:eraserfunction1(" + eventX / scalefactor + "," + eventY / scalefactor + "," + mc.getdrawAttributes1() + ")");

                            }

                            path.quadTo(mX,mY,(mX+event.getX())/2,(mY+event.getY())/2);

                            mX=event.getX();
                            mY=event.getY();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                    }

                    else if (blockerase) {

                        qx = (int) event.getX();
                        qy = (int) event.getY();
                    }

                    /*------------------Pen move on the screen following by finger-------------*/
                    else if (penmode) {

                        if(isPenDown=="true")
                        {

                            String thh1 = mc.getdrawAttributes1();
                            float width = Float.parseFloat(thh1);
                            paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
                            paint.setColor(color);
                            paint.setDither(true);                    // set the dither to true
                            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       // set to STOKE
                            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    // set the join to round you want
                            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      // set the paint cap to round too
                            paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(30) );   // set the path effect when they join.
                            paint.setAntiAlias(true);


                            //  Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
                            System.out.println("---penmove---");

                            float dx = Math.abs((int) event.getX() - mX);
                            float dy = Math.abs((int) event.getY() - mY);
                            System.out.println("--Value of dx-dy-"+dx+"-"+dy);
                            if (dx >= 4 || dy >= 4) {
                                // setXY function set X and Y values to be used in JS File
                                mc.setXY((int) event.getX() / scalefactor, (int) event.getY() / scalefactor);

                                MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:penMove(0,0,'pen')");
                               path.quadTo(mX,mY,(mX+event.getX())/2,(mY+event.getY())/2);

                                mX=event.getX();
                                mY=event.getY();

                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                        }
                    } else if (rectanglemode) {
                        qx = (int) event.getX();
                        qy = (int) event.getY();

                    } else if (linemode) {
                        qx = (int) event.getX();
                        qy = (int) event.getY();

                    } else if (circlemode) {
                        //MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:circleDown(" + eventX + "," + eventY + ")");
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    boolean ll = r.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                    if (markerMode)
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:marker12()");
                    else if (eraseMode) {
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:penUp()");
                        isEraserDown="false";
                        isMarkerDown="false";
                        System.out.println("--Eraserfromtouch---actionup");
                        path.lineTo(mX,mY);
                        mCanvas.drawPath(path,paint);
                        path= new Path();
                        // path1= new Path();
                        paths.add(path);
                      //  MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:eraserfunction1(" + eventX / scalefactor + "," + eventY / scalefactor + "," + mc.getdrawAttributes1() + ")");
                    }else if (blockerase) {

                        qx = (int) event.getX();
                        qy = (int) event.getY();
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:bigeraserfunction1(" + rx / scalefactor + "," + ry / scalefactor + "," + qx / scalefactor + "," + qy / scalefactor + ")");
                    }
                    /*---------------------Pen up for writing on canvas------------------*/

                    else if (penmode) {
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:penUp()");
                        isPenDown="false";
                        System.out.println("---pen--up---");
                       path.lineTo(mX,mY);
                       mCanvas.drawPath(path,paint);
                        path= new Path();
                       // path1= new Path();
                        paths.add(path);


                    } else if (rectanglemode) {
                        qx = (int) event.getX();
                        qy = (int) event.getY();
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:rectangle(" + rx / scalefactor + "," + ry / scalefactor + "," + qx / scalefactor + "," + qy / scalefactor + ",'" + Prefs.getString(Elucido_APP_CONSTANTS.shared_user_name, "") + "')");
                    } else if (linemode) {
                        qx = (int) event.getX();
                        qy = (int) event.getY();
                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:line(" + rx / scalefactor + "," + ry / scalefactor + "," + qx / scalefactor + "," + qy / scalefactor + ",'" + Prefs.getString(Elucido_APP_CONSTANTS.shared_user_name, "") + "')");
                    } else if (circlemode) {
                        c1x = (int) event.getX();
                        c1y = (int) event.getY();

                        MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:circleup(" + c1x / scalefactor + "," + c1y / scalefactor + ")");
                    } else if (textmode) {
                        cx = (int) event.getX();
                        cy = (int) event.getY();
                        opentextDialog((int) (cx / scalefactor), (int) (cy / scalefactor));
                    }

                    break;

                default:

                    return false;
            }


            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

**draw() Method is in thread for continuously receiving points path**

```
   public boolean draw() {
//------------------------ Starting Reciving points--------------------------
            String s1 = mc.getdrawlinesdual();
            words1 = s1.split(",");

            float xx11 = Float.parseFloat(words1[0].replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "")) * scalefactor;
            float yy11 = Float.parseFloat(words1[1]) * scalefactor;
            float xx21 = Float.parseFloat(words1[2]) * scalefactor;
            float yy21 = Float.parseFloat(words1[3].replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "")) * scalefactor;


            System.out.println("---------x" + xx11 + " y" + yy11 + " x2" + xx21 + " y2" + yy21);

            if (a1 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("----paint from pen--a1 == 0");
                Log.d("TAGG", "INTEGER value " + mc.getdrawAttributes());

                if (mc.getdrawTypeAttributes().toString().compareTo("eraser") == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Eraser--a1==0---ifllop");
                    Log.d("Eraser", "Im eraser");
                    String thh = mc.getdrawThAttributes();
                    float f = Float.parseFloat(thh);
                    paint1.setStrokeWidth(f);
                    if (bckimage == null) {
                        paint1.setColor(Color.WHITE); //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ERASE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        paint1.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Eraser--a1==0---elsellop");
                    String th = mc.getdrawThAttributes();
                    float f = Float.parseFloat(th);
                    paint1.setColor(color);
                }

                String t = mc.getdrawTypeAttributes().trim();
                if ((t.compareTo("marker") == 0)) {

                    Log.d("MARKER", "Hi im marker");
                    String col = mc.getdrawColorAttributes().substring(1);
                    col = col.toLowerCase();
                    col = "#ff" + col.trim();
                    int coll = Color.parseColor(col);
                    paint1.setColor(coll);
                    paint1.setAlpha(10);
                    paint1.setStrokeWidth(20);
                    if (bckimage == null) {
                    } else {
                        paint1.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR));
                    }
                }
                path1.moveTo(xx11, yy11);
                //  path1.lineTo(xx21, yy21);
                path1.quadTo(xx11, yy11, (xx11 + xx21) / 2, (yy11 + yy21) / 2);
                //  invalidate();
                // type.add("Line");
                path1 = new Path();
                a1 = xx11;
                b1 = yy11;
                c1 = xx21;
                d1 = yy21;
            }
            else if (a1 == xx11)
            {

                //il.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                System.out.println("----paint from pen--a1 == xx11");
                MainActivity.this.blankwhiteboard = 1;
                path1.moveTo(c1, d1);
//                float x = c+(xx2-c)/2;
//                float y= d+(yy2-d)/2;
                path1.quadTo(c1, d1, (c1 + xx21) / 2, (d1 + yy21) / 2);

                // path1.lineTo(xx21, yy21);
                 invalidate();
                c1 = xx21;
                d1 = yy21;

            }
            else
            {

                type.add("Line");
                System.out.println("----paint from pen");
                path1 = new Path();
                paint1 = new Paint();
                paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
                String th = mc.getdrawThAttributes();

                paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint1.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                paint1.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(30));
                paint1.setDither(true);

                String t = mc.getdrawTypeAttributes();
                if (mc.getdrawTypeAttributes().toString().compareTo("eraser") == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Eraser--a1!=0---ifllop");
                    System.out.println("inside cuming erase");
                    //float val = 20;
                    String thh = mc.getdrawThAttributes();
                    float f = Float.parseFloat(thh);
                    paint1.setStrokeWidth(f);
                    Log.d("Eraser", "Im in eraser");
                    if (bckimage == null) {
                        paint1.setColor(Color.WHITE); //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ERASE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else
                        paint1.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
                    invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Eraser--a1!=0---elsellop");
                    float f = Float.parseFloat(th);
                    paint1.setStrokeWidth(f);
                    String col = mc.getdrawColorAttributes().substring(1);
                    col = col.toLowerCase();
                    col = "#ff" + col;
                    int coll = Color.parseColor(col);
                    paint1.setColor(coll);
                    if ((t.compareTo("marker") == 0))
                    {
                        Log.d("MARKER", "Hi im marker");
                        paint1.setAlpha(10);
                        paint1.setStrokeWidth(20);
                        if (bckimage == null)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR));
                        }
                      paint1.setStrokeWidth(f);
                      mc.getTelephoneNumber(Integer.toHexString(color).substring(2));
                      MainActivity.super.loadUrl("javascript:colorSelectListener('')");
                    }
                  else
                    {

                    }
                }


                path1.moveTo(xx11, yy11);
              //  path1.lineTo(xx21,yy21);
               path1.quadTo(xx11, yy11, (xx11 + xx21) / 2, (yy11 + yy21) / 2);

                a1 = xx11;
                b1 = yy11;
                c1 = xx21;
                d1 = yy21;
            }
            invalidate();



//------------------------ End Reciving points--------------------------
}
```